# How to improve the Solr "OR" query performance

Tags: performance, solr, lucene

Nowdays, I've got a urgent task to improve the "OR" query performance with solr. 
I have deployed 9 shards with solr-cloud in two server(each server : 16 cores, 32G RAM).

The total document count: 60,000,000, total index size : 9G.

According to the requirement, I have to use the "OR" query to get results.

The average number of query terms is about 15.

The response time for "OR" query is around 1-2seconds(the "AND" query is just about 30ms-40ms ).

Our target : promote 50%, that is, at most 500ms-1s per query.

The document will soar to 80,000,000, however, the performance should keep in 500ms-1s query.

Any advise or approach is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do the queries look like ?

Comment: q=name:(T1 OR T2 OR T3 ....)

Comment: whats the name field ?? string ? text ?? can you use fq for it as it would cache the results ?

Comment: the name field is text. we have tried the query as: q=name:(T1 OR T2 OR T3 ....)&fq=+name:T1, it will almost promote 50%(for the number of found document has been cut down.), however, it's hard to determine which term to be chosen as T1.

Comment: Do you need the 'T' within the contents of field 'name' or could you strip that out and make that field a number?

Comment: we couldn't strip that out as a number field...

Comment: Seems likely to me that your performance is suffering on fetching documents from the index, rather than on the search itself.  That is, the size of the result set may be the problem.  How many results (`rows`) are you having Solr return from the search (pagination can help if it's large), and how large are the stored documents (smaller stored documents can improve fetch performance)?

Comment: We just get the top 100 results. Totally 11 fields, including 9 indexed field. However, the "OR" BooleanQuery search always return results more than 2,000,000, sometimes can up to 10,000,000. By adding

Comment: Appending comment: By adding some log info, we found that the BooleanScorer2.score function cost 90% time. In BooleanScorer2.score, the DisjunctionSumScorer.nextDoc cost more than 90% time of BooleanScorer2.score

Comment: What do your cache stats look like? Any evictions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try lucene-c-boost.Optimized implementations of certain Apache Lucene queries in C++ (via JNI) for anywhere from 0 to 7.8X speedup.
see
https://github.com/mikemccand/lucene-c-boost.

Comment: In spite of the highly specified some queries, it can really improve the performance almost 2x.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon if you can live without the scoring, you might want to just run multiple queries. 30-40ms * 15 => 450-600ms.

Downside is that you don't get the results scored.